# Локализация ресурсов в проектах MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

Как использовать локализацию ресурсов в проекте MFC?
Например, у меня есть два заголовочных файла:

```
#include "resource_en.h"
#include "resource_ru.h"
```

Возможно каким либо способом подключать ресурсы в зависимости от значения локальной переменной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак. `#include` разрешается на этапе компиляции (точнее, даже перед ней), а анализ значения локальной переменной возможен лишь во время выполнения.

Вы должны создать несколько локализованных DLL с ресурсами ([справка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24b2tcy0.aspx)), и нужная будет [автоматически подключена](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fkteez0.aspx).

Если вы хотите определить язык вручную, вам придётся самостоятельно найти нужную resource DLL, и подключить ресурсы из неё при помощи [`AfxSetResourceHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8ws31ff.aspx). (Детали и примеры кода, например, [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11040/Multiple-language-support-for-MFC-applications-wit).)

Comment: Мне необходимо использовать локализованные ресурсы в одной сборке, это возможно?

Comment: @ViteDecorum: То есть, вы не хотите использовать resource dll?

Comment: В принципе возможно, но не хотелось бы усложнять.

Comment: @ViteDecorum: Тогда вам придётся вкомпилировать все ресурсы в одно приложение, и как-то различать их в рантайме. Не так-то просто.

Comment: @ViteDecorum: С resource dll наоборот намного проще, поверьте.

Comment: Большего ужаса, чем локализация с помощью Dll, трудно придумать. Даже упоротые MFC-шники переходят на gettext или нечто подобное и забывают про старый подход, как страшный сон.

Comment: @zenden2k: Да ладно вам, вот WPF локализуется на раз с тем же подходом. Неужели с MFC _настолько_ всё хуже?

Comment: Можно дать пример?

Comment: @ViteDecorum: В ответе же есть ссылка в самом конце.